# Detecting ball moving between IR pair and handling ambient light changes

Tags: arduino-uno

I plan to use the [SEN-00241](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/241) IR Emitter and Detector pair to detect a ping pong ball moving fast between them.

I understand I could watch for voltage changes to detect this passing object, however how do people generally deal with ambient light changes? From my research it seems that the voltage will change with ambient light, and although I can take steps to create funnel vision between the 2 I'm sure it may still be an issue.

Would you take constant readings and find averages over 10 consecutive readings to allow for changes in ambient light and set a new baseline reading? Then if the voltage changes dramatically and only for a few reads then I know that was the ball and not to change the baseline reading.

Answer (score 1):

this is the same problem that IR remote/television has; how can TV they tell if that high voltage is a direct light or a logic 1 sent by remote? Simply because remote does not send a "HIGH" signal, but a modulated one, tipically at 36KHz. This mean a logic "HIGH" is a train of "HIGH-LOW" at 36KHz (you can see it as PWM at 50%duty cicle and 36KHz frequency)

Ambient light des not have fast variation, and inside light are at 50-60Hz, so they will be "filtered" out.

So, until you see high voltage change at 36KHz, you have your beam fine, if it is not the case, then look at voltage: if fixed at normally low voltage, beam is broken; is fixed at normally high voltage then some light stronger than your emitter is "blinding" the sensor.

note that because 36KHz is a very use frequency on Remote, there a a lot of chip that will emit or read a modulated IR, but expose a normal digital input/output, but still can be done by software, expecially if hardware assistet (like PWM for output), interrupt for input